# Postgres fails fetching data in Python

Tags: python, postgresql, bigdata, psycopg2

I am using Python with *psycopg2* module to get data from Postgres database.

The database is quite large (tens of GB).

Everything appears to be working, I am creating objects from the fetched data. 
However, after ~160000 of created objects I get the following error:

[image: Error]

I suppose the reason is the amount of data, but I could not get anywhere searching for a solution online. I am not aware of using any proxy and have never used any on this machine before, the database is on *localhost*.

Comment: Really, just using `format` is _not_ the way to create SQL queries. Use parameterization; `cursor.execute("SELECT user_id, created_at FROM cookies WHERE cookie_id = %s ORDER BY created_at DESC;", (cookie,))`. I don't know if that fixes the error but you're open to SQL injection and using string formatting is causing you hassle in trying to escape things.

Comment: Thank you @roganjosh , even though I am working on my thesis on localhost(therefore no injections), it is a valuable input for future, I have rewritten the code as you suggested in all queries.

Hilariously enough, I am at 600 000 objects and still running. You can post this as an answer and once it finishes properly, you will be accepted as a correct solution.

Comment: Okay, my RAM gave up at 900k, I have to start pickling. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's interesting how often the "It's a local server so I'm not open to SQL injection" stance leads to people thinking that string interpolation is somehow easier than a parameterized query. In your case it's ended up with:

```
'... cookie_id = \'{}\''.format(cookie)
```

So you've ended up with something that's less legible and also fails (though from the specific error I don't know exactly how). Use parameterization:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT user_id, created_at FROM cookies WHERE cookie_id = %s ORDER BY created_at DESC;", (cookie,))
```

Bottom line, *do it the correct way all the time*. Note, there are cases where you must use string interpolation, e.g. for table names:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM %s", (table_name,)) # Not valid
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM {}".format(table_name)) # Valid
```

And in those cases, you need to take other precautions if someone else can interact with the code.

Comment: Now it seems like a very newbie mistake, but it is my first time using Python with an SQL database, I mostly used it with NoSQL databases where this is not that common. Again, thank you for sparing me a lot of headaches with a strange error message.

Comment: @MichalFašánek I'd rather present it as a bit of a wrist-slap so you don't default back to `format`.... but there are _loads_ of people doing it on here so don't feel bad :) I'll preempt an issue... if you use parameterized queries and only pass one parameter, as we did here, make sure you still pass it as a tuple (note, I used `(cookie,)` with the comma). If you tried `(cookie)` it will try unpacking each individual character of `cookie`into the string and complain there aren't enough binding parameters (`%s`) to accommodate each individual character.

Comment: that is a nice detail, thank you. I will keep it in mind :) I am still wondering where that funny error line came from, other time when I ran it, it claimed I have error on some html/css line.